# how to group list of list in tcl script

Tags: tcl, grouping

i have a list of unique id, sublist of associates' id, like this:

```
5 {9 6} 
6 {9 5} 
14 {} 
1 {8 2} 
17 18 
18 17 
2 {8 1} 
8 {2 1} 
27 {} 
4 {11 3} 
3 {11 4} 
7 11 
11 {3 4 7} 
9 {6 5} 
22 {}
```

i am trying to group them by connection like this:

```
{3 4 7 11} 
{5 6 9} 
{1 2 8} 
{17 18} 
14 
27 
22
```

do not know how to do it at all. hope someone can help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried to merge the list into a single list like this:  {5 9 6}  {6 9 5} 14    

    foreach a $t1 {
        foreach {id assid} $a {
            lappend assid $id
            set assid1 [lsort -unique $assid]
            if {[lsearch $t2 $assid1]==-1} {
              lappend t2 [list $assid1]
            }
            set assid {}
        }
    }

Comment: You should add that as an edit to your question instead of the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You should traverse over the source list and perform the needed actions. For example:

```
set dest [list]
foreach { id sub_ids } $src_list {

    set found -1
    set ids [concat $sub_ids [list $id]]

    for { set i 0 } { $i < [llength $dest] } { incr i } {
        set dest_rec [lindex $dest $i]
        foreach { dest_id } $dest_rec {
            if { $dest_id in $ids } {
                set found $i
                break
            }
        }
        if { $found != -1 } {
            break
        }
    }

    if { $found == -1 } {
        lappend dest [lsort -unique $ids]
    } else {
        set dest [lreplace $dest $found $found [lsort -unique [concat [lindex $dest $found] $ids]]]
    }

}
```

Comment: seems like my acknowledgement is too early. 

https://github.com/chaujohnthan/test001/blob/master/as1.txt

Comment: it is working now seemingly. thanks.
https://github.com/chaujohnthan/test001/blob/master/td.tcl